# Converting GPS from Google Earth to Google Maps?

Tags: gps

So, I tried to take coordinated directly from google Earth kml output and use them in Google Maps, but the coordinates are different.

Google Earth output:

```
  <LatLonBox>
    <north>35.2414546011443</north>
    <south>34.54929167433407</south>
    <east>-81.5465662119679</east>
    <west>-82.32383816010319</west>
    <rotation>-1.452325961664849</rotation>
  </LatLonBox>
```

It is fairly close but not ideal. Is there spherical trignometry or something I could use?

Comment: What values are you getting in Google Maps?

Comment: @mkennedy I'm not really certain of the values: here is the map in google maps: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx17tEcqrzavUHJwdmc3aFdyckE/view In google earth it is parallel to the N.Carolina-S.Carolina Boarder, but in Google Maps it is skew.

Comment: The answer here may be the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356543/google-maps-tool-for-accurately-positioning-image-overlay However it doesn't seem to address rotations.

Comment: Spherical Trig... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624574/calculate-lat-lng-of-corners-of-ground-overlay-from-kml-file

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26598625/how-to-add-google-earth-kml-file-to-html-iframe